# JMeter - FTP sampler - Network bandwidth control

Tags: jmeter

Team,

Is there a way to change the FTP bandwidth properties ? I see there is a option for http/https under jmeter properties file. is there any similar way i can increase the FTP bandwidth ?

## httpclient.socket.http.cps=0

## httpclient.socket.https.cps=0

Answer (score 1):

JMeter doesn't throttle FTP bandwidth hence no applicable properties